# How to reset admin password if account is blocked

Tags: 8, users

I am using Drupal 8 and I forgot my admin password and have it blocked due to trying to login unsuccessfully 5 times. I am running my website in localhost.

How can I reset it? Is it possible to do with a SQL query?

Comment: Use Drush to do this. https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/user/user:password/

Comment: phpMyAdmin has nothing to do with Drupal. You're asking in the wrong place.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/44164

Comment: Here you can generate the query and run it in your Drupal Database then the password will be reset http://btobac.com/blog/mysql-query-reset-admin-password-drupal-8-drupal-7-drupal-6-phpmyadmin

Comment: @NoSssweat phpmyadmin was just the tool they were using to access the Drupal database. Arcticlisa just wanted to know how to unblock and reset a drupal admin password, which is unique to drupal.

Answer (score 5):

Drush is ideal but if you don't have that installed, you'll need to do more than just a sql query because you'll need to get a hash of the password you want to use.

First find your core drupal main directory and run

```
php core/scripts/password-hash.sh "your_new_password"
```

In phpmyadmin or your sql db manager of choice find the admin user in users_field_data and replace the pass value with the hash you got from the command above.

Then truncate the 'cache_entity' table. If you were locked out from too many failed login requests also delete instances of your IP in the 'flood' table.

Then you should be able to log in with your new password.

Answer (score 1):

with drush installed you can probably do

```
drush upwd USERNAME --password="SOMEPASSWORD"
```